# Add line-break after each 2nd period

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a solution to separate a long JSON string with line-breaks after each 2nd period.

What's wrong with this regex?

```
var text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor. Consetetur sadipscing elitr. Sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt';

text.replace(/(\.(\s+))/g, '\$1 <br><br>');

// Expected behaviour
// Lorem ipsum dolor. Consetetur sadipscing elitr. <br><br>Sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt

// Current behaviour
// Lorem ipsum dolor. <br><br>Consetetur sadipscing elitr. <br><br>Sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
```

Comment: You tell us. Given what input, what output do you get, compared to what output you expect?

Comment: So in this case you would want the line breaks added after the sentence ending with "elitr"?

Comment: I've edited my question. Excuse me.

Comment: I've made another change. Forgive me please.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly the information we need :)

Comment: does your 1st replace method parameter contains quotes, right?

Comment: @Fede Andrew Clark already posted the right answer. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
text.replace(/(\.[^.]*\.)/g, '$1 <br><br>');
```

The `[^.]*` will match any number of characters that are not periods, so this regex will match exactly two periods with anything in between them.

Comment: Damn, the solution was so easy and I was so fkn%&% stupid... thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

```
text.replace(/(.*?\.){2}/g, '$& <br><br>')
```

This will expect two chunks of text with a period, then replace them with the match followed by line breaks.

You could easily play with the number if you feel like making the breaks more sparse.